# Calculating percentage returns integer

Tags: ruby

I have two integer values `dicount_percentage` and `price`. When I run the following command, it always returns `0` rather than the discount value etc.

```
price*(discount_percentage/100)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: How can you fix what? What is "the discount value etc."?

Comment: s/dicount_percentage/discount_percentage/

Comment: I don't know a lot about ruby, but I know in most other languages, int values are truncated. Ergo, `15/100 = 0.15` and an `int` value of `0.15` gets truncated to `0`. Ints typically don't like division- you want a float or double or some other decimal-supporting number type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast one of `price` or `discount_percentage` to float:

```
price*(discount_percentage.to_f/100)
```

Comment: In 9 mins, I will :)

Answer (score 1):

```
price*(discount_percentage/100.0)
```